# php output directory was not found

Tags: php

I'm trying to save a file inside php: // output to send it as an answer (it's an excel).
The problem is that php does not find the directory, according to the documentation should be able to access it.

i add this validation to my code:

```
$folderName = 'php://output';
if(!is_dir($folderName)){
            throw new FileNotFoundException($folderName . " directory not found.");
        }
$objWriter->save($filePath);
```

and the exception has been throwed and return me:

```
"php://output directory not found.",
```

Comment: Maybe because `php://output` is not a directory?

Comment: No, the problem is that you are using `is_dir` on something that isn’t a “directory”, not even remotely.

Answer (score 2):

`php://output` is not a directory; it's an output stream. You use `php://output` to write stuff to the output buffer the same way `echo` or `print` does. For example, if you wanted to force the browser to display a PDF or an image straight away without saving it first, you would use `php://output`.

If you wanted to physically save the file in your filesystem then a proper path must be used.